# How do we give ImageCardViews placeholder images while the poster loads?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have a wrapper class that contains the ImageCardView and loads an image fetched from the Web into it. Before the network call is made, I have

```
        imageCardView.getMainImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_movie_placeholder);
```

For some reason, the image never comes up if I have the network call take place right afterwards, even though it takes maybe .5-1.5 seconds for an individual poster to come up. But if I comment out the network call and assignment, the image comes up. How do I make it so that the placeholder is visible while the poster is being fetched? I use Picasso to do this, does Picasso clear the image view before it loads?

Answer (score 1):

I think Picasso does clear the image when you call the `load(url).into(imageView)` method in order to avoid displaying incorrect images on a listView/recyclerView.

What you could use is Picasso's own way of setting a placeholder image, which works like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_movie_placeholder)
    .into(imageView)
```

This way Picasso will show your `icon_movie_placeholder` drawable until the network request finishes, and if you need to provide a placeholder image you can use the builder's `error(resourceId)` method just like that.

You can find more info about this on Picasso's official Github page (specially under the **Features** section: http://square.github.io/picasso/